# When packaging gems with an application, can one run the application one another computer with only installing the correct ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, user-experience

I have a ruby application I would like to package and distribute. The application is dependent on a few gems. This is a question about user experience.

I want the user to be able to download a folder and run my application. At most, the user will have to download and install the correct version of Ruby as a requirement.

Will running 'bundle package' be enough to cover the gem dependencies?

I have also explored bundling the running environment with ocra but I think that is over kill and to much of a knock on performance.

Comment: Depends on if the gems include ones which have native extensions.

Comment: Can I get an example of a native extension?

Comment: I am most concerned with knowing whether the application will work even if the user has never installed any other gems.

Comment: Any extension that says “Building native extensions…” while installing. Depending on the platform and setup of the user they may not run when packaged.